# bash text processing to remove ascii and get unique lines from the result

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

In linux, below command

```
terraform providers
```

output the result as below

```
.
├── provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi] 1.2.0
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes] 2.3.2
├── provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas] 1.0.1
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
├── module.standard_deployment
│   ├── provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas] 1.0.1
│   ├── provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi] 1.2.0
│   ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes]
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local]
└── module.standand_ingress
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes]
    ├── provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas] 1.0.1
    ├── provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi] 1.2.0
    └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]

Providers required by state:

    provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas]

    provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes]
```

What is the best way to remove those tree structure from the output?
The end goal is to list only unique lines as below,

```
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi] 1.2.0    
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas] 1.0.1
```

Comment: Why is  `provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes] 2.3.2` missing from the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and `sort`, you can try this

```
$ sed -E 's/.*(provider.*)/\1/g;/^[a-z]/!d' input_file | sort -u
provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes]
provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes] 2.3.2
provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local]
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas] 1.0.1
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi] 1.2.0
```

This may not be the most efficient however.

**EDIT**

Taken from the comment by Hai Vu, here is a grep alternative that worked for OP.

```
terraform providers | grep -o 'provider.*[0-9][^]]*$' | sort -u
```

Comment: I like this solution. An alternative to the `sed` command is `grep -o 'provider.*$'`

Comment: so with `terraform providers | grep xxx.com | grep -o 'provider.*$' | sort -u`  I got the output as                                                                                                                               `provider[fid.com/edu/fidsmaas]
provider[fid.com/edu/fidsmaas] 1.0.1
provider[fid.com/edu/fidvenafi]
provider[fid.com/edu/fidvenafi] 1.2.0`    Now I want to keep only lines with version

Comment: With `sed` you can combine the filters: `terraform providers | sed -n 's/.*\(provider.*xxx.com.*\)/\1/p' | sort -u`

Comment: I am close now, But I want to keep only lines with version (1.0.1 or 1.2.0). With what Walter and Hatless gave, output has lines without version also. I updated original post's  with what the output I want.

Comment: @user2068179 `terraform providers | grep -o 'provider.*[0-9][^]]*$' | sort -u`

Comment: @user2068179 You're welcome.  I will add it to my answer in that case since it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/[0-9]$/ && sub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/,"") && !seen[$0]++' file
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi] 1.2.0
provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes] 2.3.2
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas] 1.0.1
```

or if you really only want lines ending in 1.0.1 or 1.2.0 as you said in a comment:

```
$ awk '/ 1\.((0\.1)|(2\.0))$/ && sub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/,"") && !seen[$0]++' file
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxvenafi] 1.2.0
provider[xxx.com/edu/xxxsmaas] 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
terrraform providers |
  awk 'BEGIN {FS="provider"}
    /xxx.com/ && NF==2 {printf("%s%s\n", FS, $2)}' | 
  sort -u
```

or avoiding the call to `sort`:

```
terrraform providers |
 awk 'BEGIN {FS="provider"}
   /xxx.com/ && NF==2 {a[$2]}
   END {
     for (key in a) {
       printf("provider%s\n", key)
     }
   }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/.*(provider)/\1/;ta;$!d;bb;:a;H;g
         s/((\n\S+\]).*)\2[^\n]*$/\1/;h;$!d;:b;x;s/.//p' file
```

Turn off implict printing `-n` and turn on extended regexp `-E`.

Match on lines containing `provider`, remove any preamble and jump forward to `:a`.

If a match was not found and is not the last line, delete it and repeat.

If a match was not found and is the last line, jump forward to `:b`.

At `:a`, append the current line to the hold space and then copy the hold space over the current line.

Using pattern matching, compare previous line keys with the current line key and remove the current line if the key has already been added.

Copy the result to the hold space, and if not the last line delete and repeat.

At the end-of-file `:b`, swap to the hold space, remove the introduced newline at the start and print the result.